# Is there a way to get a reference back to the original element a function making an Ajax call was associated to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very new to front end programming here so apologies if I've just completely botched this conceptually from the bottom up!

I've got a Flask driven site where I have four select boxes, populated with values representing row IDs into a database table, with each select having an img and a p associated to it. When the user chooses an item from a drop down, the image and  paragraph that's associated to that drop down should update based on information from an AJAX call. I've got the AJAX call successfully being made upon the user choosing a new selection. Where I'm stuck is how to utilize the getJSON callback function to correctly identify the select element that made the call so I can traverse the DOM to find its sibling img and p. Once I'm in the callback function, it seems like $(this) no longer refers to the element that made the original function call and I'm having difficulty figuring out where to go from here. Most examples I've researched explaining the Asynchronous nature of AJAX only demonstrate the callback function updating something simple, such as the contents of a paragraph on a page with only that one paragraph ($("p")) as opposed to anything more targeted so I'm a little lost on next steps.

### HTML template

```
    
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="./getfile" method="POST">
            <div class="container">
                    {%for i in range(0, 4)%} <!-- Create 4 sets of selects/paragraphs/imgs -->
                    
                <div>
                    <label>Class {{ i + 1 }}</label>
                    <select class="job_id_option" id="job_id{{i + 1}}" name="job_id{{i + 1}}"> <!-- When this select changes, the sibling p and img should change based on an AJAX result -->
                            {% for job in jobs %}
                            
                        <option value={{ job.id }}>{{ job.name }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        
                    </select>
                    <p id="job_details">Blah blah blah blah</p> <!-- this p's contents should change based on AJAX result -->
                    <img src="static/graphics/FIGHTER/idle.bmp" id="promoted_class_sprite"/> <!-- this img's src should change based on AJAX result -->
                </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                
            </div>
            <label for="start_promoted">Start Promoted</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="start_promoted" name="start_promoted" value="True" checked>
                <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Get Patch" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

### Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $(".job_id_option").change(function(){
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/getclassdetails', {
            job_id: $(this).val()
            }, function(data) {
                console.log("Retrieved from server: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                $("p").filter("#job_details").html("You did it");
                $("img").filter("#promoted_class_sprite").attr("src", "static/graphics/" + data.short_name + "/idle.bmp");                  
        });
    })            
});
```

The code as written right now is successfully updating all of the paragraphs and images on the page with the given ids, as expected. I'm still considering exactly how to get back to the select that made the function call within the AJAX callback function. My initial thought was to have the /getclassdetails AJAX call also return the value that was passed to it, so I could have jquery look for select elements that have that value and update any matching element's siblings. However, I want to dig a little deeper and determine if I'm missing or misunderstanding something about the nature of the callback functions before I start altering the python back end functions to return back a request detail that is otherwise unneeded. Is there a smarter way to go about what I'm attempting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't repeat element ID's in a page, so convert to classes instead.

What you want is to traverse to the `<p>` and `<img>` that is in same parent `<div>`.

You can do that several ways by using `parent()` and `find()` or using `next()` for the `<p>`

```
$(".job_id_option").change(function(){
     const $div = $(this).parent(),  
           $para = $div.find('.job_details')// or $(this).next(),
           $img = $div.find('.promoted_class_sprite')

     $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/getclassdetails', {job_id: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
          $para.html('...')
          $img.attr('src'....
     })

})
```

Comment: This did the trick. I think I was under the impression that those variables would not be within the scope of the callback function, which in one iteration of the code I was working through I think may have actually been the case (I had the AJAX call in its own separate function). Also, thanks for the tip off on the element IDs!

Comment: Well you were sort of thinking correctly. `this` inside the `getJSON` callback would not work unless you used an arrow function and that is why the variables are created outside it